# Is there possibility of exporting mathematica code directly into $\LaTeX$?

Tags: graphics, export, latex

I'm a very novice  user of *Mathematica* - is there possibility of exporting Mathematica code directly into $\LaTeX$? I'm interested only in exporting mathematical formulas. Also, from which version of program is it possible?

Comment: You've seen `TeXForm[]`?

Comment: See also this question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34997/1089

Comment: It is possible from the very beginning: it was introduced in 1988 (1.0) and updated in 2004 (5.1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select the text, right click, and select Copy As -> LaTex.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Mathematica help system has useful information, and links to videos etc.

[image: help screen]