# Export Code to Pseudocode?

Tags: programming, export, latex, code-generation

I'm writing a paper and all my code is in *Mathematica*. The snippets are mostly simple, and consist of loops, maps, variables, and conditionals. I'd like add it to my paper, however, not many academic journals accept verbatim code in a specific language, and I'm short on time, so here is my question:

**Does anyone know of a package that translates *Mathematica* functions and code to pseudo-code?**

Of course there is no universal syntax pseudo-code, but I'll accept anything that is adequately general (bonus points for robust exportability to $\LaTeX$). Here are some examples of this utility in other languages:

- http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/Products/CodeRocketEclipse
- http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Pseudocode-Generator-sjETRTxkP2.html

When writing papers I always do the translation by hand, but enough is enough, *Mathematica* should excel at a high-level translation problem like this and at least get the bulk of the work done for me! I use the [pseudocode environment](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/pseudocode/pseudocode.pdf) from the `fancybox` package to typeset pseudocode into $\LaTeX$.

Please note that I fully intend on trying to write an answer to this myself, so don't down vote for the lack of code just yet! `:)`

Comment: +1, but I always wanted a package able to do it the other way around and can interpret my **"Now get all those solutions"** pseudocode comments

Comment: Me too! Alas that direction is much much harder :/ I have a friend who believes that smart and visual programming languages in the next 10 years will have this ability.

Comment: Perhaps `SpokenString` or `CompilePrint` could come in handy.

Comment: But now with all those upvotes you sure gotta deliver ;-)

Comment: IMO this is problematic due to the ill-defined nature of "pseudocode", dependent as it is on the expectations of the audience. I actually dislike pseudocode descriptions in papers since normally they are written in an inappropriately procedural style and often contain various bugs due to the fact that they can't actually be executed to check for correctness. I would suggest translating to some widely used, free and open language such as Python and providing the code in the supplementary materials. Another good alternative to pseudocode is a flowchart.

Comment: This could be extremely useful for writing papers :) Please someone answer this question!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here is my attempt to generate a pseudocode for *algorithmicx* package.

### Current features

- Functions (as `SetDelayed`)
- `Set`
- `If` with 2 and 3 arguments
- `While`
- `Do` (any number of variables of any type) **New!**
- `Return`
- `Module`, `With`, and `Block`
- `CompoundExpression` (`;`)
- Test functions (`EvenQ`, etc., and `Not@EvenQ`, etc.) **New!**
- Indentation

### Code

```
ClearAll[pseudocode, pscd]
SetAttributes[{pseudocode, pscd, texstring}, HoldFirst];

indent[n_] := "\n" <> ConstantArray[" ", n];

pscd[SetDelayed[f_[x___], code_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\Function{" <> pscd@f <> "}{" <> 
   Riffle[pscd@Hold@x, ","] <> "}\n" <> pscd[code, n + m, m] <> 
   indent[n] <> "\\EndFunction\n";
(*SetDelayed as a function*)

pscd[pattern_, n_: 0, m_: 0] /; Head@Unevaluated@pattern === Pattern :=
   pscd /@ pattern // First;
(*remove patterns from arguments of functions*)

pscd[(Module | With | Block)[{vars___}, code_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  Cases[Hold@vars, s_ /; Head@Unevaluated@s === Set :> pscd[s, n, m]] <> 
   pscd[code, n, m];
(*remove everything from Module,With,and Block except code and setting of variables*)

pscd[set_, n_: 0, m_: 0] /; Head@Unevaluated@set === Set := 
  indent[n] <> "\\State " <> 
   Riffle[pscd@# &@ReleaseHold[Hold @@@ Hold@set], " $\\gets$ "] <> "\n";
(*Set*)

pscd[CompoundExpression[code___], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
 Riffle[pscd[Hold@code, n, m], "\n"] <> "\n"
(*...;...;*)

pscd[If[cond_, true_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\If{" <> pscd@cond <> "}\n" <> pscd[true, n + m, m] <>
    indent[n] <> "\\EndIf\n";
(*if*)

pscd[If[cond_, true_, false_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\If{" <> pscd@cond <> "}\n" <> pscd[true, n + m, m] <>
    indent[n] <> "\\Else\n" <> pscd[false, n + m, m] <> indent[n] <> 
   "\\EndIf\n";
(*if... else*)

pscd[While[cond_, code_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\While{" <> pscd@cond <> "}\n" <> 
   pscd[code, n + m, m] <> indent[n] <> "\\EndWhile\n";
(*while*)

pscd[Do[code_, args__, arg1_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  pscd[Do[Do[code, arg1], args], n, m];
(*nested do*)

pscd[Do[code_, {i2_}], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\Do{" <> pscd@i2 <> "}\n" <> pscd[code, n + m, m] <> 
   indent[n] <> "\\EndDo\n";
pscd[Do[code_, {i_, i2_}], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  pscd[Do[code, {i, 1, i2}], n, m];
pscd[Do[code_, {i_, i1_, i2_}], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\For{" <> pscd@i <> " = " <> pscd@i1 <> " \\ldots " <>
    pscd@i2 <> "}\n" <> pscd[code, n + m, m] <> indent[n] <> 
   "\\EndFor\n";
pscd[Do[code_, {i_, i1_, i2_, di_}], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\For{" <> pscd@i <> " = " <> pscd@i1 <> ", " <> 
   texstring[i1 + di] <> " \\ldots " <> pscd@i2 <> "}\n" <> 
   pscd[code, n + m, m] <> indent[n] <> "\\EndFor\n";
pscd[Do[code_, {i_, l_List}], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\For{" <> pscd@i <> " = " <> 
   Riffle[pscd /@ l, ", "] <> "}\n" <> pscd[code, n + m, m] <> 
   indent[n] <> "\\EndFor\n";
(*do*)

pscd[q_[x_], n_: 0, m_: 0] /; (Last@# == "Q" && LowerCaseQ@#[[-2]] &)@
   Characters@ToString@Unevaluated@q := 
 pscd@x <> " is " <> Riffle[StringCases[ToString@q, 
    A_?UpperCaseQ ~~ b__?LowerCaseQ :> ToLowerCase@A <> b], " "]
(* convert EvenQ[x] to "x is even" and so on *)

pscd[Not@q_[x_], n_: 0, m_: 0] /; (Last@# == "Q" && LowerCaseQ@#[[-2]] &)@
   Characters@ToString@Unevaluated@q := 
 pscd@x <> " is not " <> Riffle[StringCases[ToString@q, 
    A_?UpperCaseQ ~~ b__?LowerCaseQ :> ToLowerCase@A <> b], " "]
(* convert Not@EvenQ[x] to "x is not even" and so on *)

pscd[Return[x_], n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
  indent[n] <> "\\State \\textbf{return} " <> pscd@x <> "\n";
(*return*)

pscd[h_Hold, n_: 0, m_: 0] := 
 List @@ Function[{x}, pscd[x, n, m], HoldAll] /@ h
(*Automatically transform Hold[x,y,...] to {pscd[x],pscd[y],...}*)

pscd[code_, n_: 0, m_: 0] := texstring@HoldForm@code;
(*default*)

texstring[code_] := "$" <> code~ToString~TeXForm <> "$";
(*sometimes we need to convert without holding *)

Options[pseudocode] = {Indentation -> 2};
pseudocode[code_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  CellPrint@TextCell[StringReplace[
     "\\begin{algorithmic}\n" <> 
      pscd[code, OptionValue@Indentation, OptionValue@Indentation] <> 
      "\\end{algorithmic}", "\n" .. :> "\n"], "Output"];
```

For indentation I use `n` and `m` variables. `n` is the current indentation and `m` is the step of the indentation.

### Examples

#### Example 1

```
pseudocode[
 max[a_, b_] := Module[{r},
   If[a > b, r = a, r = b];
   Return[r]]
 ]
```

Output:

```latex
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Function{$\max$}{$a$,$b$}
\If{$a>b$}
  \State $r$ $\gets$ $a$
\Else
  \State $r$ $\gets$ $b$
\EndIf
\State \textbf{return} $r$
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

#### Example 2

```
pseudocode[
 gcd[a_, b_] := Module[{r = Mod[a, b], x = a, y = b},
   While[r != 0,
    x = y;
    y = r;
    r = Mod[x, y]
    ];
   Return[y]
   ]
 ]
```

Output:

```latex
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Function{$\gcd$}{$a$,$b$}
\State $r$ $\gets$ $(a \bmod b)$
\State $x$ $\gets$ $a$
\State $y$ $\gets$ $b$
\While{$r\neq 0$}
  \State $x$ $\gets$ $y$
  \State $y$ $\gets$ $r$
  \State $r$ $\gets$ $(x \bmod y)$
\EndWhile
\State \textbf{return} $y$
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

#### Example 3

```
Do[i = i + n + m + k + l, {n, 10}, {m, 5, 20}, {k, m, 30, 2}, 
   {l, {1, 3, 5, 8}}, {40}] // pseudocode
```

Output:

```latex
\begin{algorithmic}
  \For{$n$ = $1$ \ldots $10$}
\For{$m$ = $5$ \ldots $20$}
  \For{$k$ = $m$, $m+2$ \ldots $30$}
    \For{$l$ = $1$, $3$, $5$, $8$}
      \Do{$40$}
        \State $i$ $\gets$ $i+n+m+k+l$
      \EndDo
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\EndFor
  \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

#### Example 4

```
If[! HermitianMatrixQ[H], H = H + ConjugateTranspose[H]] // pseudocode
```

Output:

```latex
\begin{algorithmic}
  \If{$H$ is not hermitian matrix}
\State $H$ $\gets$ $H+H^{\dagger}$
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

$\LaTeX$ example file:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algrenewcommand\textproc{}% Disable uppercase in functions

%necessary for "do ... times" constructions
\algblockdefx[DO]{Do}{EndDo}[1]{\textbf{do} #1 \textbf{times}}{\textbf{end do}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
    ...
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Let me know if you find a bug!